# Why is my function for google sheets returning TypeError: given_list is not iterable? Or: How can I input an array into a google sheets function?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm making a custom function in google sheets which counts the number of occurrences of all items in a given array in a given range of cells.

The way I'm given to understand google sheets functions work are that the range you give is turned into a two-dimensional array of the items in the cells. So range A4:B5 would be transmitted to the function as

```
[[the contents of A4, the contents of B4], 
[the contents of A5, the contents of B5]
```

The next input is a list of the items to check for in those cells. From what I could find [online](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en), arrays are given in google sheets by using brackets like these {}. the function I created is given below. I have never used javascript before but I know other languages and I just googled how to use for loops and if statements to create the function, so I'm certain the error is due to something simple that I don't know about or missed.

```
function count_if_in_set(range, given_list) {
  let counter = 0;
  for (dim_1 of range) {
    for (dim_2 of dim_1) {
      for (item of given_list) {
        if (item == dim_2) {
          counter += 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return counter
}
```

When I try to use this function in google sheets with the following input: `=count_if_in_set(Z30:Z33, {1})`, I receive the following error: `TypeError: given_list is not iterable (line 5).`

The contents of cells Z30 to Z33 are the integers 1, 2, 3, 3 which should be given to the function as the following 2-dimensional array: `[[1], [2], [3], [3]]`

The problem is that the list `[1]` is not iterable. I have 2 hypotheses as to why this is:

1. I coded something wrong because I'm very new to Javascript
2. The input {1} is not transmitted to a list when google sheets gives it to the function

To check if it was the former, I went through all the aspects of my function. I first checked if you have to declare the type of variable it was when you created the function, but according to what I saw when I googled it you don't. I then changed all my `for (a of b)` to `for (let a of b)` but that did nothing to help, and after that I was stuck.

To try and solve it in the case it was a problem with giving the code an array, I tried changing my input from `=count_if_in_set(Z30:Z33, {1})` to `=count_if_in_set(Z30:Z33, [1])`, but that threw up a formula parse error so I knew that wasn't it, and I tried changing the input to `=count_if_in_set(Z30:Z33, (1))` but that returned the same error. And after that I was stuck and had no more ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the same result with a plain vanilla spreadsheet formula, like this:

`=arrayformula( countif(Z30:Z43, { 1, 2, 3 }) )`

To get just the grand total, use this:

`=arrayformula( sum( countif(Z30:Z43, { 1, 2, 3 }) ) )`

To count how many cells have a text string that *contains* one of the search keys, use this:

`=arrayformula( sum( countif( Z30:Z43, "*" & { "a", "b" } & "*" ) ) )`

If you *need* to use a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) for some reason, try something this to get started:

```
function count_if_in_set(values, given_list) {
  let counter = 0;
  values.map(row => row.map(value =>
    counter += (given_list.indexOf(value) !== -1)
  ));
  return counter;
}
```

This is really an anti-pattern, because the `map` result is not used for anything. People would tend to use `Array.reduce()`, but the `map-map` pattern may be easier to follow, and it is the one typically employed in custom functions that most often do not aggregate the result but return exactly one value per argument value.

Some of the best resources for learning Google Apps Script include the [Beginner's Guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-beginner-guide/), the [New Apps Script Editor guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-ide/), the [Fundamentals of Apps Script with Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-fundamentals-1) codelab, the [Extending Google Sheets page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets), [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/), [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) and [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).

Comment: Thanks! The vanilla function worked great, but then I ran into a case where I realised I actually need something like what I assume the code version does, which is count it if the item appears anywhere in the cell - for example when counting "a", "b", a cell containing "ab" would be counted twice as opposed to no times. I tried implementing the code you gave but it gave me the following error: TypeError: given_list.indexOf is not a function (line 4). when I entered only one item into the list, and always returned 0 when I put more than 1 item in the list. Do you know why that happened?

Comment: Or, do you know any way to do that sort of thing? Searching to see if the boxes contain the items, not just are equal to the items?

Comment: ok I figured it out! only works for string items though.
format them each like this: "*a*", "*b*", etc. Then it'll detect each time each item shows up, or if you sum them, the total time each item shows up. It can therefore exceed the number of cells, e.g. cells "a", "b", and "ab" would have a total of 4 occurrences of a and b. Hope this helps anyone else looking for this niche function
EDIT: it will not count multiple occurrences in the same box. cell "abb", "aaabbababab", and "ab" are in it's eyes the same. Just in case it's relevant to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Just looking for the number of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 or 9 in  the selected range and return the item and count

```
function checkforitems(a, b) {
  let obj = {pA:[]};
  Logger.log(a);
  Logger.log(b);
  let arr = b[0];//b enters as a 2d array with a single element
  //collect counts with a pivot table
  a.forEach(r => {
    r.forEach(c => {
      let index = arr.indexOf(c);
      if(~index) {
        if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(arr[index])) {
          obj[arr[index]]=1;
          obj.pA.push(arr[index]);//collect elements as an array
        } else {
          obj[arr[index]]+=1;
        }
      }
    });
  });
  let l = '';
  //obj.pA.sort((x,y) => x - y);//if searching for numbers you can use this to sort them before displaying them 
  obj.pA.forEach(e => {
    l += `${e}-${obj[e]}\n`;
  });
  return l;
}
```

My Test Sheet:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 17 | 8 | 10 | 2 | 7 | 4 | 19 | 12 | 11 |
| 8 | 13 | 7 | 1 | 6 | 14 | 8 | 19 | 15 | 1 |
| 17 | 15 | 15 | 6 | 7 | 3 | 3 | 17 | 8 | 12 |
| 8 | 2 | 17 | 9 | 9 | 7 | 15 | 16 | 19 | 11 |
| 14 | 11 | 19 | 0 | 15 | 4 | 16 | 11 | 1 | 11 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 | 19 | 3 | 1 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 16 |
| 10 | 8 | 8 | 2 | 17 | 18 | 0 | 1 | 17 | 6 |
| 1 | 0 | 10 | 18 | 12 | 16 | 11 | 4 | 7 | 13 |
| 10 | 18 | 6 | 12 | 12 | 5 | 3 | 11 | 9 | 5 |
| 13 | 2 | 2 | 8 | 5 | 4 | 8 | 12 | 18 | 2 |
| 0 | 18 | 18 | 18 | 17 | 4 | 6 | 14 | 8 | 8 |
| 1 | 11 | 12 | 1 | 15 | 17 | 18 | 3 | 0 | 6 |
| 19 | 5 | 17 | 11 | 12 | 9 | 12 | 1 | 6 | 15 |
| 12 | 5 | 7 | 1 | 14 | 9 | 4 | 4 | 18 | 12 |
| 3 | 1 | 11 | 8 | 11 | 9 | 17 | 6 | 12 | 5 |
| 11 | 12 | 16 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 6 | 12 | 3 | 5 |
| 16 | 0 | 18 | 14 | 8 | 4 | 16 | 0 | 10 | 0 |
| 15 | 13 | 4 | 17 | 14 | 10 | 9 | 9 | 2 | 4 |
| 13 | 12 | 11 | 15 | 12 | 18 | 0 | 8 | 19 | 19 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 3 | 1 | 16 | 18 | 6 | 1 | 2 |

My formula (L22):

=checkforitems(A2:J21,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9})

returned result:

```
1-16
8-14
2-8
7-6
4-11
6-10
3-12
9-8
5-11
```

Test Sheet With Results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To anyone looking for a way to make that function work:

I did the same thing but changed it slightly so the second input was a range of cells which contained the range I wanted to search through